# integrate my magento 2 store with different 20 ecommerce websites to sale products of that sites on my store

Tags: magento2

i have magento2 store that is based on  purse and handbags ......i want to integrate my magento2 store  to top 20 e-commerce websites like amazon, e-bay, snap-deal, flip-kart....and sale inventory of  that sites like different types of bags only on my store is it possible.? then suggest me the procedure...I searched about this related issue on google but, got solution by adding the extension in the magento admin panel. Only alone the ebay extension costs $199, so for all 20 sites the cost will be too expensive and also i had only wanted purse and bags products from the inventory of these websites, but only thing is do these sites such as amazon provide inventory for only selective categories i.e. only for purse and bags. please any suggestion or guide. thank you..

Comment: The integrations that you are looking to do are extremely complex and very difficult to implement in Magento 2. I don't think you are going to find native solutions to all of these sites (amazon and ebay exist, but not many more) and those integrations are going to be from different solution providers. 3rd party systems exist like Channel Advisor, but these are very expensive solutions and might not be something you want to pay for. But for what you are looking to do, they might just be the only game in town.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look for a solution from cedcommerce integration? They have very economical integration cost. I used them for one of my clients in past for eBay, Amazon & many another marketplace. They are working good

Write back to me I can provide further details